# Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8080 || POSTMAN

Tags: java, intellij-idea, postman

I'm working on a small project and I have to send a post request in postman, but I continue to get to connect, ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8080 error occurred.

I've already checked that I'm using the correct port and changed a few proxy setting to try and fix the problem, but nothing seems to work. When I run the project on IntelliJ, I have no errors, so I really don't know how to solve the problem.

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8080
Request Headers
Content-Type: application/json
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.29.2
Accept: */*
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 6ea87f2c-511f-4124-a1ac-3c7d29fb6c81
Host: localhost:8080
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
```

Comment: Please add screenshot of request in postman.

Comment: ECONNREFUSED means that the TCP/IP connection wasn't accepted, which means you can easily ignore any headers, because the problem happens way before they are found. What's the output of `netstat -tlpn` on your machine (that's on Linux, no idea how to get that on Windows). Where is the server running that you're trying to connect to? What happens when you contact `http://127.0.0.1:8080` in your browser?

Comment: if you are on *nix based system, please check if your server is indeed running using `lsof -i :8080` command and check process id, kill if you want to restart it again